# div dissapear after including php

Tags: javascript, php

When I want to include my search in index.php, slider.php just disappears.

The file search.php is combination of php and javascript and slider.php is pure javascript.

This is my index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mhgallery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/initgallery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <?php include 'includes/search_form.php';?>

        <?php include 'includes/slider.php';?>


    </body>
</html>
```

This is search.php:

```
<?php
include 'init.php';

$output="";
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace ("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("error");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($count == 0){
        $output = 'No resault';
    }else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $username = $row['username'];

            $output .= '<div>'.$username.'</div>';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

This is search_form.php:

```
<?php include 'php_script/search.php';?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="search_box">
    <form action = "index.php" method="POST">
        <input id="box" type="text" name="search" placehoalder="Search" onkeydown="searchq();"/>
    <input id="srch" type="submit" value=">>"/>
    </form>

    <div id="output">
        <?php echo ($output);?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is slider.php:

```
<div id="mhgallery">
    <style type="text/css"> #mhgallery img { display:none; } </style>
    <img src="slideshow_slike/batman.jpg" title="batman" />
    <img src="slideshow_slike/hobbit.jpg" title="hobbit" />
    <img src="slideshow_slike/interstellar.jpg" title="interstellar" />
    <img src="slideshow_slike/sw7.jpg" title="sw7" />
</div>
```

This is initgallery.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#mhgallery").mhgallery({width:950,height:400,scaleMode:'scaleToFill',firstSlide:0,randomPlay:false,autoPlay:true,backgroundMode:'transparent',backgroundColor:'#333333',showShadow:true,showThumbShadow:true,showPause:false,showBorder:true,borderSize:6,borderColor:'#FFFFFF',showFullscreen:false,fullscreenBackgroundColor:'#333333',fullscreenThumbArrowStyle:'white',interval:3000,effectSpeed:500,showCaption:false,textCSS:'.title {font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;color:#ffffff;line-height:200%;} .alt {font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;color:#ffffff;}',captionPosition:'bottom',captionBarColor:'#333333',captionBarOpacity:0.8,captionBarPadding:8,captionAlign:'center',showNavArrows:true,autoHideNavArrows:true,arrowStyle:'white',showThumbs:false,thumbSize:40,thumbGap:8,thumbBottom:-60,thumbArrowStyle:'black',thumbOpacity:0.8,thumbBorderWidth:1,thumbBorderColor:'#FFFFFF',thumbBorderActiveColor:'#FFFFFF',effect:'fade,slideLeft,slideRight,slideTop,slideBottom',jsFolder:'js'});});
```

This is search.js:

```
function searchq(){
    var searchTxt = $("input [name='search']").val();
    $.post("search.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function (output){
        $("#output").html(output);
    });
}
```

Comment: `value=">>"/>` this is wrong

Comment: not directly related, but important: ***Please stop using the `mysql_*` extension***: It's _deprecated_. Read [The red warning box](http://php.net/mysql_connect), click the links and choose the replacement extension you like best (`PDO` or `mysqli`). `PDO` is more widely used, its API is clean, and intuitive. `mysqli` is messier, but is slightly more powerful

Comment: Please stop using MySQL_*, it is depreciated and should no longer be used. Look at MySQLi or PDO as alternatives.

Comment: @u_mulder what's wrong with that?

Comment: Something in `search_form.php` is creating an error, causing php to stop execution. Turn on error reporting to find out the cause

Comment: @Steve i turned on error reporting but no errors

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!
i deleted 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> in search_form.php because it was duplicate.
Thanks all for help!